# QTree is not a member of package com.twitter.algebird

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark

I'm trying to use QTree and QTreeSemigroup in the algebird package but am unable to import them in the spark-shell.

I tried both:

```
spark-shell --jars ~/jars/algebird-core_2.10-0.1.11.jar

SPARK_CLASSPATH="~/jars/algebird-core_2.10-0.1.11.jar" spark-shell --jars ~/jars/algebird-core_2.10-0.1.11.jar
```

and I'm able to successfully import algebird like this:

```
import com.twitter.algebird._
```

But when I try to import Qtree I get that they are not members of the algebird package:

```
scala> import com.twitter.algebird.QTree
<console>:22: error: object QTree is not a member of package com.twitter.algebird
       import com.twitter.algebird.QTree
              ^

scala> import com.twitter.algebird.QTreeSemigroup
<console>:22: error: object QTreeSemigroup is not a member of package com.twitter.algebird
       import com.twitter.algebird.QTreeSemigroup
```

What gives?! Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was using an old version of algebird. Works with the latest.